# Is it OK to WebScrape YouTube CONTINUOUSLY?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, youtube

I made a simple web scraper (python, selenium) that scrapes the LiveChat of a YouTube Livestream.  I want to scrape once every second, but I heard someone mention that scraping >5/second is against YT's TOS. (I am a creator and don't want to get in trouble by doing this)

I have looked on their [TOS](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms), but could not find anything about this. Does anyone have experience/ know anything about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a lawyer or web-scraper.
Concerning the TOS of YouTube, in the german verions (I dont know how to access it in english, but they should be the same) there is stated under the point "Permissions and Restrictions" that you are not allowed:

> 3. To access the service with automated processes (e.g. robots, botnets or scrapers), with the exception of (a) via public search engines according to YouTube's Robots.txt file, (b) with prior approval by YouTube in text form or (c) to the extent permitted by applicable law.

(Google-Translated)

So by just using the Scraper you should be violating the TOS.

I dont even know if you wouldn't have to solve a captcha at some point because a lot of google-services have it running in the background (see [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)).

Comment: Do you think "the exception of (a) via public search engines" applies here because I am having selenium actually open up a driver window in order to scrape public data?

Comment: I dont think this applies here. I think this is thought for Google. DuckDuckGo, Bing, etc.
and not for in your case *private* Scraping.
But if you dont shoot over the top with your scraping and your scraper isnt traceable back to your youtube account, e.g. via Proxy or something, you could get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe as long as you do not spam youtube, you should be good to go.

but they may detect your activity and block your ip. but there's always be a cooling period so I guess it shouldn't bother you much.

also cause you are not actually inserting anything, just extracting the text, try to put some `sleep()` in between so that it will be tough for Youtube bot to detect your activity.